# Make PHP variable from other variable

Tags: php, variables

I use TMDB v3 api for my site.
I want to make these variables:

$item1 = "first item id in upcoming movies"
$item2 = "second item id in upcoming movies"
$item... = "... item id in upcoming movies"

I tried to make, and my result up to now this:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$pelinfo11 = $tmdb_V3->upcomingMovies($page=1);
foreach ($pelinfo11['results'] as $element1) {  
echo "<p>".$count." - ".$element1['id']."</p>";
$count++;
} ?>
```

But I can't make the variables with $count.

Comment: And why can't it just use an array, like `$item[1]` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using array..

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$pelinfo11 = $tmdb_V3->upcomingMovies($page=1);
$items=array();
foreach ($pelinfo11['results'] as $element1) {  
$items[]=$element1['id'];
echo "<p>".$count." - ".$element1['id']."</p>";
$count++;
} 

var_dump($items);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very basic concept of PHP is - you can not use expression to create a variable. A variable is actually a storage. You can dynamically access it once created.

You can use array instead.